# Optimizing Boot-up

Tags: boot, optimization

I installed [bootchart](http://www.bootchart.org/) to monitor my boot-up process.

I had some problems with my booting time (>80sec)
Before :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tvky.png

After some tweaking with Bum,Ubuntu-tweak and Start-up Manager i reached (>30sec)
After :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4Pyf.png

**Is it good ? or is there room for more ?**
What Boot-up time(range) is normal ? ( of course it depends, but on default setting on a mid/high-tech pc)

Comment: I think 30 seconds is a pretty good boot if you have a hard disk.

Comment: yep 30sec is amazing for a hdd. But imagine you have a SSD -> then all the red stuff will disapear. RedStuff = CPU has to wait for your HDD

Comment: Its a good result =) , 80 seconds is a bit too long . While boot time is estimated 10~40 sec (estimations) .

Comment: My machine boots in 24 seconds on a 5400rpm HD. Sometimes though it has a minute long boot though, probably setting up something.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only thing that stands out for me in that bootchart is the (relatively) long period from ~6sec to ~11sec into the boot where the disc throughput is very low.  This suggests that `ureadahead` is doing a lot of (slow) seeking rather than (fast) linear reads.  Making `ureadahead` reprofile your boot may help here.  Deleting the `.pack` files in `/var/lib/ureadahead` will cause `ureadahead` to reprofile next boot.

Answer (score 1):

From what I'm seeing I think that you might be going as fast as you can. About the only thing I could think of doing would be to make a custom kernel specifically for your hardware, but I don't know how much of a speed boost that would give you.

Answer (score 0):

e4rat if you use Ext4. But prefferably with "lite-git" versions.
Ureadahead is nice for SSD disks. For HDD (on Ext4) you can gain more by using e4rat (but you NEED to disable ureadahead).

e4rat will move files needed for booting and login (and whatever you start during first 120sec. - good if you always start some app at startup). And "-lite" variants will load only small portion of needed files to RAM and rest parallel to normal startup. That cut some seconds on slow HDDs when you need to load lots of stuff.

(Also you have there Apache + mysql, which you can disable if you do not need it all the time, as both can be easily started from cli in no time letter)